# How can I change the person running the script from an editor to a viewer

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script that when the function is ran, it will add a new owner and change the person running the script to view only.   I got the ownership change to work well, but I can't figure out how to change the person running the script's ownership from editor to viewer.

```
function submit(){
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = as.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var submitTo = "fake@arsu.org";
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  file.setOwner(submitTo);
//  file.addViewer(me); // keeps me as an editor
//  file.removeEditor(me); //removes me all together
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do those last two operations in the opposite order?

Comment: @Mogsdad : It removes them as an editor after which he doesn't have any sort of access to the file. Hence, the last command of adding them back as a viewer does not really happen.

Comment: Thanks @pointNclick - although what I was really hoping was that the question would get edited with the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this function in many different ways and the one that came closest to the solution was this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = as.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var submitTo = "xyz@gmail.com";
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

  file.addViewer(me); // keeps me as an editor
  file.setOwner(submitTo);
  file.removeEditor(me); //removes me all together
}
```

Adding yourself as a viewer does not work because soon as you set someone else as an owner and remove yourself as an editor, it becomes their document and would need their permission to give you any sort of further access. This allows you to request for permissions as the code ends up sending you an email for the file and allows to request for view permissions from the new owner. (<-- This was happening in your original code as well.)

Another scenario I tried was commenting out the line `file.removeEditor(me);` allowed me to transfer ownership while keeping the View and Edit permissions of the document. If you are expecting to view the document after transferring ownership I would suggest you to go this route because in various scenarios tried thus far, this is the only one that comes the closest without blocking you out of the document.

Hence, depending on your use-case, I would suggest you to follow either of these 2 scenarios.

Comment: If you are a domain administrator you could hand off the editor removal part to a second script.